# Youtube API Subscription.ContentDetails.NewItemCount returning zero if querying myself but return different value from Google API Explorer

Tags: youtube-api

When using the [youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#try-it) to get the list of my subscriptions and all the related details I get a number of information from the snippet and contentDetails part of the response object.

When I call the service from my script the contentDetails.newItemCount always return zero, this [should indicate](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions) the number of new videos on the channel since last time I've opened the channel. The contentDetails.totalItemCount (total number of videos for the channel) is accurate instead.

In contrast if I run the same query through the [google api explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.subscriptions.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&maxResults=50&mine=true&_h=1&), the same variable contains the correct information and not zero.

The call I make from my PHP script is exactly the same as the one run on the google api explorer so I can't explain or understand why I'm getting different results. The code I use is roughly the following

```
$this->_youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($this->_connector->_googleClient);
  $params = array('mine' => true,'maxResults'=>25,'order'=>'alphabetical');
  $part = 'snippet,contentDetails';
  $response = $this->_youtube->subscriptions->listSubscriptions(
                    $part,
                    $params
                );
  foreach ($response['items'] as $item) { 
     $this->_mysubscriptions[] = array(                                                        
        'channelId'=>$item['snippet']['resourceId']['channelId'],                                                        
        'title'=>$item['snippet']['title'],                                                        
        'description'=>$item['snippet']['description'],                                                        
        'thumb_default'=>$item['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'],                                                        
        'thumb_medium'=>$item['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url'],                                                        
        'thumb_high'=>$item['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['url'],                                                        
        'subscribedOn'=>$this->cleanDate($item['snippet']['publishedAt']),                                                        
        'totalVideos'=>$item['contentDetails']['totalItemCount'],                                                        
        'newVideos'=>$item['contentDetails']['newItemCount']);
  }
```

This is how the object returned looks like (just removed few IDs from the response) from the google API explorer, while when I run it through my code I get the same data but the newItemCount is zero.

`{
   "kind": "youtube#subscription",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2016-09-14T12:48:00.000Z",
    "title": "Muselk",
    "description": "\"Memes win games\" - Youtube.com/mrmuselk",
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#channel",
     "channelId": "UCd534c_ehOvrLVL2v7Nl61w"
    },
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-iWlz7dePNz0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/smtPKh-RLTU/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-iWlz7dePNz0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/smtPKh-RLTU/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-iWlz7dePNz0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/smtPKh-RLTU/s240-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     }
    }
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "totalItemCount": 792,
    "newItemCount": 4,
    "activityType": "all"
   }`

I've looked through the [revision history](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history) but can't find any reference of modifications made to this specific property of the contentDetails object

There is a [bug filed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35174656) with google on this property but it refers to a different behaviour.

Wondering if this happens to other as well, or if somebody can give some hints on how this works or don't.

Comment: Can you try performing a call to [Subscriptions.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#try-it)? After a successful call, fetch the whole response where newItemCount is included under items and debug if value is stil zero.

Comment: @noogui that's exactly what I do. I call the listSubscriptions method of the Youtube API Service Object, what I get is all the correct details but newItemCount is always zero. When I do the same the call through the API Explorer the value of newItemCount is correct. I use the same parameters, same object, same method. Unless they add something I can't see from the page